# How to manipulate a wav file's data via its binary file in python

Tags: python, wav, binaryfiles

I'm trying to manipulate a wav file's data (change the metadata to put in a url in the comment section) by using its binary structure, or in other terms change its binary structure. Here is my attempt at trying to do so:

```
with open('test.wav', 'r+b') as f:
    b = f.read()
    l = b.find(b'\x00ICMT') + 1 # Find the position after ICMT
    v = b.find(b'\x00ICRD') - 1 # Find the position before ICRD
    f = bytearray(b) # Make f into a bytearray
    f[l:v] = b'URL: RandomURL' # Use l and v to get the section I want to rewrite (comment section)
```

In the code above I'm trying to convert the wav file into a byte array and then find the position after ICMT (comment section in the metadata) and the position when ICMT's section ends (before ICRD's section). I then use this information to access the comment section within the byte array and make that into a byte that has the url. However, whenever I try this I don't actually change the contents of the wav file, it seems. What is wrong with my approach or is there an easier way to manipulate the binary contents of a wav file to get what I want?

Comment: `f.read()` consumes all characters in the file stream, so the next time you call `f.read()` there will be nothing left to read. Read from the file once and store its contents in a variable, so that they can be inspected more than once.

Comment: Okay, I created a variable b = f.read() and used that instead of f.read() but that still didn't work.

Comment: Is it failing in the same way as before? Have you tried opening the file in `rb+` mode, rather than `r+b`?

Comment: Oh wait, you're expecting `f[l:v] = ...` to change the contents of the file? That's definitely not going to work. You need to make your changes to a bytearray, open the file for writing, and write the bytearray to it.

Comment: Each chunk (which is the correct term) in a RIFF file has a header with the length of the chunk.  The `ICMT` token there is followed by a 4-byte length field.  What you're doing will change the length of the section without updating the headers.  You can't change a WAVE file in place like that.  You should use the Python `chunk` module to copy to a new file.  It was designed for RIFF files.

Comment: I just tried rb+ and is still doesn't work, it seems as if nothing is actually changed within the wav file itself. Could this be due to me making a bytearray which is separate from the actual wav file?

Comment: You aren't manipulating the file.  You read the contents into an array, and then dink with the array.  Nothing changes on disk until you do `f.write`.

Comment: Ahh okay can I use the code above and apply the `chunk` module to it (I added a line which would write the bytearray to the file)?

Comment: Sort of.  You need to understand the RIFF format.  The chunks are nested.  The whole file is a RIFF chunk, which (optionally) contains a LIST chunk with the metadata.  Each of those has a length that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Can you give an example of doing that? @TimRoberts

Comment: I guess the `chunk` module doesn't really buy anything, and it's read-only.  See if this helps.  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/37bfe560bfa27ab661238f3bdfa317e6

Comment: Yeah that helps tremendously! @TimRoberts